# Add "Contact Us"/"Support" link to the Sing-In form

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I want to add a link directing users to our support to the Azure B2C Login form.

I don't see any way of doing it.

There is a "support" URL in [Application Manifest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#informationalurls-attribute) but

- it doesn't seem to be used ([at least it's not documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-terms-of-service-privacy-statement))
- it's displayed when consent is asked for the application, not on the login form

Is it possible to add a custom link to the [standard layouts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) of Azure B2C or do I need to use a the [HTML templates approach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy)?

Even using the HTML templates I think I will only be able to add the link somewhere else on the page, not to the login form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is the HTML form as you mentioned. You can add the link on the login form. You'll just need to add a div with your link. If you're having trouble getting it to work let me know and I can help you out.

Best,
James

Comment: Can you post an example of what you mean as it's not clear to me now?